# Cordova volume button feature on Android app

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i am working on creating android app using cordova to make a call. 
I wanted to  add a volume button on my android app to increase and decrease volume during video call through app screen without touching Android hardware. i would highly appreciate for any suggestion and sample as well.

I found this plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-volume

But do not have idea how i implement it , any help would be higly appreciated.
eg

how can i use below function from above plugin to control volume
window.androidVolume.set(volume, showToast, success, error)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at different plugins?

https://github.com/MCluck90/cordova-plugin-android-volume#readme